# HTML Form submit event lost if DOM was modified through AJAX

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I have a form with input fields and submit button. Each input's blur event is observed (using prototype) and a new Ajax.Request is fired for server side asynchronous validation. The Ajax response text modifies the DOM tree by updating the error texts and error div styles. Everything works fine, except when I left some input element, click the submit button and the DOM is modified in the meanwhile because of the AJAX response.

In short, the submit button's onclick event and the form's event onsubmit are not fired if the DOM is modified through the AJAX call in the meantime.

This is the code:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() { 
    $$('#customerForm input[type=text],#customerForm select').each(function(node){
        node.observe("blur",function(){
            var formData=$('customerForm').serialize(true);
            var fieldName=this.name;
            var fieldId=this.id;
            var errDivId=this.id+'_err';
            var errDiv=$(errDivId);
            var parent=$(errDiv.parentNode);
            formData['fieldName']=fieldName;
            new Ajax.Request(
                validateUrl, 
                {
                    method: 'post', 
                    parameters: formData,
                    onComplete:function(response){
                        var responseText=response.responseText;
                        responseText=responseText.strip();
                        errDiv.innerHTML=responseText;
                        if(responseText==""){
                            errDiv.removeClassName('errors');
                            parent.removeClassName('errors');

                        }
                        else{
                            errDiv.addClassName('errors');
                            parent.addClassName('errors');
                        }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or if this is expected behavior, is there any workaround? The expected result should be a form submission, no matter if the DOM is modified or not after the button's click.

Comment: Is there more javascript? This code should not interfere with submit(), I suspect there's another script thats blocking the submit.

Comment: No this is the only javascript. If I delay the server response, for example with Thread.currentThread.sleep(500), there is no problem. So it seems if the DOM is modified between submit button's focus and click, tne click event is lost (I checked this).

Comment: Based on the above, there is a dirty workaround that works well. We can track the submit button's focus and blur events with a variable: submitFocus=true/false. 

$('create').observe("focus",function(){
 submitFocus=true;
});
              
$('create').observe("blur",function(){
 submitFocus=false;
});

Based on this value the ajax response update action should be delayed if the submitFocus=true.

if(submitFocus)
 window.setTimeout(function(){
  updateError(responseText,errDiv,parentErrDiv);
 },500);
else
 updateError(responseText,errDiv,parentErrDiv);

Answer (score 1):

hint 1: try not to update whole DOM on Ajax requests, that's a better attitude, only get JSON responses and put values in error showers

hint 2: don't know about Prototype (never used it) but jQuery has live() besides the standard bind(), which always listens to the event firing and is killed by calling die() on the same element

hope this helps in any way

Answer (score 0):

There is a dirty workaround that works well. We can track the submit button's focus and blur events with a variable:

```
submitFocus=true/false. $('create').observe("focus",
    function(){
        submitFocus=true;
    });
$('create').observe("blur",function(){
     submitFocus=false;
});
```

Based on this value the ajax response update action should be delayed if the `submitFocus=true.`

```
if(submitFocus)
   window.setTimeout(function(){
       updateError(responseText,errDiv,parentErrDiv); },500);
else
   updateError(responseText,errDiv,parentErrDiv);
```

Comment: [Answered by the OP in a comment; converted to a community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat).